# How to make sliders and text field compatible?

Tags: flutter

This is the GitHub link for the project

https://github.com/ParamJain07/Flutter-Sip-Calculator

When I run the above program the sliders work properly but it stays at a random no.

I want to divide it specifically. Can you please tell me what should I do to do that?

I tried the division's tag after the minimum tag in Windows layout.dart at 106 line but it didn't work.

In this can you help me by making the text field which is connected with the slider compatible and giving me the expected results?

It basically means what should I do to make the text field and sliders connect and when I type some no. in the text field the slider should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the above program the sliders work properly but it stays at a random no.
> I want to divide it specifically. Can you please tell me what should I do to do that?

The slider won't be able to select properly with a large range, you will lose accuracy, and cannot select the values correctly. If you need to have this large range, and don't need the user select the unit, only de dozen or hundred, you can use something like this:

```
SfSlider(
   min: 1,
   max: 300,
   value: value,
   onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
        variableThatIsPrinted = value * 10; //If you want select only dozen
        variableThatIsPrinted = value * 100; //If you want select only hundred
        });
   }),
```

Using like this, you will have only 300 points in your slider, but can reach until 3000 or 30000 values.

> It basically means what should I do to make the text field and sliders connect and when I type some no. in the text field the slider should get updated.

The TextFormField have a property called onUpdate, and it will return the value of the field when you change it, you can put that value in your variable that is link to Slider. You need to have attention to not receive other values besides numbers, use RegExp to this.

Hope it helps, and I am here if need more help.